# How to call UseEffect when data comes into material table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I wanted to call a function when data comes into the material table (https://github.com/mbrn/material-table). I tried to use this.

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(ref.current.state.data);
        //Do stuff
});
```

For some reason useEffect is called only when data is empty. Which means ref.current.state.data is an empty array.

A few moments later, when data comes into the material table, useEffect is not called. A data change does not trigger useEffect, why is that? Or is this a concept that I do not understand about refs?

PS: Material table uses Material UI.

Comment: ref doesn't trigger re-render so your useEffect won't be called.

Comment: A ref change does not trigger a re-render as demonstrated in this [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-gould-9ex81).

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the data as dependency, so whenever it changes, the useEffect will trigger.

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(ref.current.state.data);
        //Do stuff
}, [<your-data>]);
```

Comment: He isn't using a dependency, his useEffect always runs

Comment: Problem here is that I cannot use ref.current as a dependency, it does not work. If I use data as dependency, the problem is that after data variable gets some values, table still remains empty for a few seconds so I am not able to use ref.current.state.data in my function as it will still be empty.